# Snackbar not being dismissed on action click

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin, android-button, snackbar

Through a click event, I'm trying to close a `Snackbar` whenever it is open. However, for some reason, it doesn't get dismissed, despite opening successfully.

- If the `EditText` is empty, I want the `Snackbar` to appear
- else if the `EditText` is not empty, I want the `Snackbar` to be dismissed

I tried using this, but it didn't work:

```
if (mSnackbar.isShown) {
    mSnackbar.dismiss()
}
```

Would a callback need to be used in this situation? If yes, I'm not sure where it needs to go.

```
val mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(mRootView, "Hello World", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
val mEditText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text) as EditText
val mBtn = findViewById(R.id.my_btn) as Button

mBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (mTextView.text.isEmpty()) {
        mSnackbar.show()
    } else {
        if (mSnackbar.isShown) {
            mSnackbar.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are trying to show in button click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
mBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (mTextView.text.isEmpty()) {
        mSnackbar.show()
    } else {
        mSnackbar.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting at `else` try to create a `Log` below the `else` and check if the condition works at the `if statement` and `else`

Comment: Why I have added this code it is.
At the button click listener, checks if text is empty show snackbar otherwise dismiss.
Thanks for accepting my answer.